# Outlook PRF settings for TLS encrypted connection

Tags: outlook, ms-office

We use the PRF file settings to inject email settings into Outlook, but I cannot find which settings to change in the ".prf" file to enable TLS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer for setting TLS settings. Set the `SMTPSecureConnection` string value as follows:

- 0 for none
- 1 for SSL
- 2 for TLS
- 3 for Auto